# Calling methods based on variable (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, methods

I have a number of different Coregraphics functions drawing out different elements of a clockface. The logic I am looking to put together determines which aspect of the clockface is displayed based on the variable pulled from the current hour. All of the draw methods are listed in a separate swift class/file. Rather than creating this tower of if statements, how can I simplify this process to inject a variable into the method called? In this you can see that drawCanvas04() is associated with 4:00pm (or 16 hours).

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func updateTime() {

    var date:NSDate = NSDate()
    var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
    var hour = components.hour
    var minute = components.minute
    var seconds = components.second

    var time = "\(hour) : \(minute) : \(seconds)"
    println("\(time)")


    if hour == 16 || hour == 04 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas04()

    } else {

        if hour == 17 || hour == 05 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas05()

    } else {

        if hour == 18 || hour == 06 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas06()

    } else {

        if hour == 19 || hour == 07 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas07()

    } else {

        if hour == 20 || hour == 08 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas08()

    } else {

        if hour == 21 || hour == 09 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas09()

    } else {

        if hour == 22 || hour == 10 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas10()

    }

    if hour == 23 || hour == 11 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas11()

    }

    if hour == 24 || hour = 12 {

        ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas12()

    }
```

}

Here is an example of the stylekit draw method being called:

```
public class func drawCanvas07() {
    //// Color Declarations
    let color0 = UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.000, blue: 0.476, alpha: 1.000)

    //// HOUR7 Drawing
    var hOUR7Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(65.5, 155.99, 24, 24))
    color0.setFill()
    hOUR7Path.fill()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters. Also cut down on class methods, use instance methods instead like `self.drawCanvas()`.

Like so:

```
func drawCanvas(canvas:Int) {
    switch canvas {
        case 0:
        // do something here for 0 o clock
        case 1:
        // 1 o clock
        // etc,
        default:
        // in case somehow you run out of bounds
    }
}
```

and call it using `drawCanvas(10)`.

Comment: Should the drawrect method sit in a different class, or does it need to be nested with the time calculation method? I'm having difficulty structuring the code to pass the hour variable without triggering a "Cannot invoke 'drawCanvas' with an argument list of type '(Int)' error.

Comment: Also it seems the only way I can use the instance method self.drawCanvas is when I call it from the StyleKit file, otherwise it begs me for a ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas().

Comment: Once again, don't use class methods. You were using class methods, thats why you had to do `ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas()`.

Comment: @softdownfeathers would be great if you could mark this as correct so others can refer to it as a solution :-)